DS160 and i20 discrepancy regarding sponsors
There is a discrepancy between my i20 and my DS160 form. In my i20 it is written as family funds but in my DS160 it is written as I'm sponsoring myself.I can change my DS160 before my biometric interview.
I have to fill out a new DS160 form and in that I will fill in that my parents are sponsoring and take the old and the new DS160 to the biometric interview.
Will the visa officer on the day of my interview get to know what have I changed and what the difference between my old and new DS160 form is?

Yes they can see everything but if you are going with new DS160 their focus is on that one instead old one
